# Ubicar todos los enlaces de un sitio en un único archivo

Tags: php, html, jquery, rutas

Quiero tener un único archivo para poner allí todos los enlaces que se encuentran en mi sitio y así de esta manera ubicarlo en el pie de cada una de mis páginas. Sólo tendría que hacer algo como `<?php include("include/Pie.php");?>` para cada archivo.

El problema es que esos archivos (en donde iría, para el ejemplo, la llamada a  `Pie.php`) son algunos de tipo `.html` y en estos casos no puedo hacer uso de `php` para poner la línea del `include`. Tengo muchísimos archivos con extensión `.html` y no sé si es conveniente cambiarlos por la extensión `.php`, es que creo que perdería el posicionamiento que tengo de esas páginas.
Por eso, ¿hay alguna otra forma de realizarlo? También leí algo sobre el uso de `JQuery`, pero por lo que he leído (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages) los enlaces aparecerían ocultos para los rastreadores.

También está el tema de las **URLs relativas** o **URLs absolutas**. Yo ahora las tengo como relativas, pero, ¿las tengo que cambiar a absolutas no?, ya que mis diferentes archivos están en diversas carpetas; por lo cual los accesos cambian según desde que página se llame a cada uno de los enlaces que estarían en el archivo `Pie.php`

¿Qué me recomiendan hacer con todo esto? ¿de qué manera es conveniente y que a la larga sea eficiente?

Answer (score -1):

No entiendo porque dices que pierdes la posicion en internet.
Primero eso es falso y te explico porque.
los archivos **.php** se tratan igual que los archivos **.html** y resultan mucho mas utiles ahora bien si el dilema es cual utilizar te propongo que uses la extencion **.phtml** que tambien es correcto.
Ahora puedes utilizar un rutero para manejar tus rutas a tu disposicion de esta forma no es necesario que la pagina **HOME** se llame asi, con el rutero puedes llamarlo inicio o **START** consulta sobre eso o formula tus inquietudes yo te ayudo...